# Codedom generate complex if statement

Tags: c#, code-generation, codedom

I'm a bit stuck with try to generate a complex if statement like the one below

```
if (class1.Property == class2.Property || (class3.Property && class4.Property))
{
  //do something
}
else
{
   //do something else
}
```

By using the CodeConditionStatement class I can generate the first condition above but I can not seem to find a way to add the second condition especially with the needed brackets and the way if will be evaluated at runtime?

Note: I do not want to use the CodeSnippetExpression class.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The inner brackets are useless in the posted example, because the result is the same with or without them (even the order it is evaluated should be the same)!

Comment: ...although it does help visualise an expression tree that could represent the condition

Comment: changes the bool logic of the code example to need the brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a simple way would be to declare a boolean variable.
Initialize it to false and to the sequence of if manipulating that variable.
Don't worry about performance or readibility, sometime it is more readable.

```
bool x = false;
if (class1.Property == class2.Property)
{
    x = true;
}
if (class3.Property == class4.Property)
{
    x = true;
}

if (!anotherthingtocheck)
    x = false;

if (x)
{
    // Do something
}
else
{
    // Do something else
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Separate the condition into 3 binary expressions: `(class1.Property == class2.Property || (class3.Property || class4.Property)`

1. `class3.Property || class4.Property` - CodeBinaryOperatorExpression with  CodePropertyReferenceExpression on left and right
2. `class1.Property == class2.Property` -  CodeBinaryOperatorExpression with  CodePropertyReferenceExpression on left and right
3. Finally `#2 || #1` - CodeBinaryOperatorExpression #2 on left and #1 on right

Answer (score 0):

Simplified to just compare booleans, but retaining the if, else...

```
CodeEntryPointMethod start = new CodeEntryPointMethod();
//...
start.Statements.Add(new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement(typeof(bool), "ifCheck", new CodePrimitiveExpression(false)));
var e1 = new CodeBinaryOperatorExpression(new CodePrimitiveExpression(false), CodeBinaryOperatorType.IdentityEquality, new CodePrimitiveExpression(false));
var e2 = new CodeBinaryOperatorExpression(new CodePrimitiveExpression(false), CodeBinaryOperatorType.IdentityEquality, new CodePrimitiveExpression(true));
var ifAssign = new CodeAssignStatement(new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("ifCheck"), new CodeBinaryOperatorExpression(e1, CodeBinaryOperatorType.BooleanOr, e2));
start.Statements.Add(ifAssign);
var x1 = new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement(typeof(string), "x1", new CodePrimitiveExpression("Anything here..."));
var ifCheck = new CodeConditionStatement(new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("ifCheck"), new CodeStatement[] { x1 }, new CodeStatement[] { x1 });
start.Statements.Add(ifCheck);
```

generates:

```
bool ifCheck = false;
ifCheck = ((false == false) 
    || (false == true));
if (ifCheck) {
    string x1 = "Anything here...";
}
else {
    string x1 = "Anything here...";
}
```